# Calculate difference between two values, when Customer_ID is the same

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of transactions where the date is registered as yyyymmdd (20200101) and a related Customer_ID is associated, I need to calculate the difference among the consecutive dates that have the same Customer_ID. They are not subsequent, but disperse over a series of transactions.

Comment: So what's stopping you? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I don't have any solutions in mind!

Comment: Well it's time to start then. Have you not had a look at the date functions, such as `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: Ahaha! Yes I have, but then how to do the difference only when I have the same Customer_ID?

Comment: What version(s) of SQL Server will you need to run on? Some of the recently added features might help here ...

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) 
Thanks if you can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `lag()` function to fetch the related previous record.

**Sample data**

```
declare @data table
(
    id int,
    stamp nvarchar(8) --recommend to use 'date' for date values...
);

insert into @data (id, stamp) values
(1, '20200101'),
(2, '20200102'),
(1, '20200105'),
(2, '20200107'),
(3, '20200108');
```

**Solution**

```
select  d.id,
        convert(date, d.stamp) as DateStamp,
        lag(convert(date, d.stamp)) over(partition by d.id order by d.stamp) as DateStampPrev,
        datediff(day, lag(convert(date, d.stamp)) over(partition by d.id order by d.stamp), convert(date, d.stamp)) as DiffInDays
from @data d
order by d.stamp;
```

**Result**

```
id          DateStamp  DateStampPrev DiffInDays
----------- ---------- ------------- -----------
1           2020-01-01 NULL          NULL
2           2020-01-02 NULL          NULL
1           2020-01-05 2020-01-01    4
2           2020-01-07 2020-01-02    5
3           2020-01-08 NULL          NULL
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this concludes your question, then you can formally "accept" my answer to remove your question from the pile of unanswered questions.